# Find eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

I don't understand how to find this one way I know to find characteristics polynomial then try to solve but it's tooling and I m stuck in calculation please help to give some easy way for solving this problem

Comment: Do you know anything of the relationship of trace and eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes I know but for that i need at least one eigenvalue trace =sum of eigenvalue value.,set=product of eigenvalue

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda_1 = a + b i$ be the eigenvalue, since the matrix is real, this implies the second eigenvalue comes in the conjugate pair $\lambda_2 = a - bi$. Then since there are three eigenvalues, the third one is necessarily real, we note that the trace of a matrix is the sum of the eigenvalues and so we have
$$ \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 2a + \lambda_3 = 20.$$
Which implies that the other eigenvalue must be $\lambda_3 = 20 - 2 a$.

Comment: Can anything more be said of $\lambda_3$ for this particular matrix?

Comment: Sure. You could calculate the eigenvalues if you want, but I don't believe the purpose of the question is to calculate it in detail.